# Edited: `layout_below` relative to `layout_centerVertical="true"`

Tags: android, view, android-relativelayout

A quick question: I want to put  `view1` below `view2` that has the property `layout_centerVertical="true"` in a `RelativeLayout`. Obviously, `android:layout_below="@id/view2"` does not work, even there is a lot of space available.

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/image1"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/view2"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/image2" />
```

Now, I have found what causes this. I have an another view:

```
<View
        android:id="@+id/view3"
        android:layout_width="10dip"
        android:layout_height="10dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#fff" />
```

If this view has the property `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` everything relative to `view2`(the centered view) is going crazy in the layout(dissapear), but strange, `view2` stay unmoved. If I change to `android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"` everything is going back to normal. I don't understand, `view3` has nothing to do with other views. Is any rule that I don't respect? Please help me. Any answer it will be appreciated.

Comment: better u post ur code

Comment: "Obviously, android:layout_below="@id/view2" does not work," why not?

Comment: @codeMagic, I don't know, otherway, the problem would be solved.

Comment: Yes, but its not obvious that it doesn't work. What are you getting? How isn't it working opposed to how you want it to work was the question

Comment: @codeMagic `layout_below=@id/view2` is just ignored

Comment: Ok, but where is `view1` being placed then? It seems to be working for me after changing it to `layout_below=@+id/view2` besides the fact that you have `padding` on `view2`

Comment: @codeMagic Yes...I have placed it in a new layout and it works... this makes me thing, that it is a mistake somewhere in my code.. I will search for it.

Comment: Sometimes Eclipse doesn't recognize xml changes right away and a simple clean/rebuild solves those kinds of issues. That may have been the problem

Comment: @codeMagic Yes, the EclipseLayoutEditor was the problem. After some clean/close-open it was solved.This is not the only problem caused to me, I think I'll try AndroidStudio.

Comment: @AlexAndro Try AS at your own risk. It is still very very new and you will have even more problems with that, especially if you are a beginner. I play with it but I still use Eclipse as my main editor for now. I haven't used IntelliJ but I hear its real good and similar to what AS is suppose to be.

Comment: @codeMagic can you take a look to my edited answer? Please.

Answer (score 0):

i recommend using a `tableLayout` or a `GridLAyout`.

Something like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
<TableLayout 
     android:gravity="center_vertical" >      // <-- that one is required!
    <TableRow 
         android:gravity="center">                                 
        <TextView />            
        <ToggleButton />            
    </TableRow>                  
    <TableRow >                                 
        <TextView />           
        <EditText />            
    </TableRow>        
</TableLayout>   
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: how does this center the first view vertically?

Comment: i removed the layout_gravity, thought that would have been obvious.